# Count the zeros in Sudoku

Tags: java, sudoku

I want to count the number of zeros(`0`) in the array using `countCellsToFill()` .
I tried looping with `count+1` which is returned. But it does not appear in the output. Anybody please help me to complete this.

```
public class Sudoku{

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
    int[][] sudokuPuzzle = {    
                         {8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9},       
                         {0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},                                                                                       
                         {3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1},
                         {0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 2, 7, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 7, 1, 0, 0},
                         {1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2},
                         {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
                         {2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5}
                    };  
    printSudoku(sudokuPuzzle);
}
 public static void printSudoku(int[][] sudokuPuzzle)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < sudokuPuzzle.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 3 || i == 6)
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        for (int j = 0; j < sudokuPuzzle[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.format("%-2s", sudokuPuzzle[i][j]);
            if (j == 2 || j == 5 )
                System.out.print(" | ");
        }           
        System.out.println();   
    }      
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "using countCellsToFill()"?  You haven't included that method in your question, nor does your code use it anywhere.

Comment: @azurefrog countCellsToFill() is not yet used.. i would like to use this method to count the number of zeros.. zeros here are meant to be blank space in sudoku. Simply i want to count the cells have to be filled.

Comment: @Tippu I cannot find any `count + 1` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int countCellsToFill(int[][] arr){
    int count=0;
    for(int[] r : arr){
        for(int a: r){
            if(a == 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

In the main method at the end:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
{
    //......

    printSudoku(sudokuPuzzle);
    int count = countCellsToFill(sudokuPuzzle);
    System.out.println("Num of zeros: " + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<sudokuPuzzle.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<sudokuPuzzle[i].length; j++) {
        if(sudokuPuzzle[i][j] == 0){
            count++;
        }

    }
}
```

Simply loop through and count the 0 cells?